# python read and process each line in file using while and for loop

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

Input: A .txt file contains lots of lines of '$GPGSV,1,1,01,01,,,26*7D'

Output: 26

```
import subprocess
import csv
from string import split

f = open('GPS_SNR.csv', 'wb')

while True:
    with open('EMNA_GPS.txt', 'r') as g:        
        for line in g: 
            tempstr = line.split(',')[7]
            GPSstr = tempstr.split('*')[0]
            print GPSstr
            GPS = float(GPSstr)
            print type(GPS)
            wr = csv.writer(f, dialect = 'excel')
        wr.writerow([GPS])
        g.close()
```

What happen:
The infinite loop never stops...lets say there are 100 lines in the file; however, there are thousands of lines wrote into the .csv instead of 100 lines.

Should I use 'if = EOF' statement?

Comment: That's because you never call `break` on your `while True:` loop.

Comment: Some notes: A) You used a `with` statement to open `g`; you don't need to (and shouldn't) explicitly `close` it, that's what the `with` statement does for you. B) You _should_ use a `with` statement opening `f` (which you neglect to `close`; failing to do so for files opened for write is more likely to cause problems). C) Drop `from string import split`; it's an archaic API; the `split` method on `str` doesn't require a special import. D) That text file looks like it's really CSV; any reason not to parse it as such? The file extension is not important if the data is actually CSV data.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the unnecessary while loop. You iterate over the lines in the text file, so you do not need it.

```
import csv
from string import split

f = open('GPS_SNR.csv', 'wb')

with open('EMNA_GPS.txt', 'r') as g:        
    for line in g: 
        tempstr = line.split(',')[7]
        GPSstr = tempstr.split('*')[0]
        GPS = float(GPSstr)
        wr = csv.writer(f, dialect = 'excel')
        wr.writerow([GPS])
```

Comment: He also shouldn't create a new writer for each line.  That line should go before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop will iterate over each line in the file.
Python automatically checks for the End of file and closes the file for you (using the `with open` syntax).

```
import csv

with open('EMNA_GPS.txt', 'r') as g, open('GPS_SNR.csv', 'wb') as f: 
    wr = csv.writer(f, dialect = 'excel')
    for line in g: 
        tempstr = line.split(',')[7]
        GPSstr = tempstr.split('*')[0]
        print GPSstr
        GPS = float(GPSstr)
        print type(GPS)    
        wr.writerow([GPS])
```